# PHPExcel - Set Background Image

Tags: php, phpexcel

Does anyone know how to set a background image in the excel generated using PHPExcel. I can see only the option to insert image in a cell. 
This option is similar to what we do in the normal excel - Page Layout => Background.
Please help me.

Comment: Technically, images aren't inserted into a cell; they overlay the spreadsheet

Comment: But look at the [Page setup options](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#setting-the-print-header-and-footer-of-a-worksheet)